# Cannot implicitly convert ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am getting an error that states that I cannot implicitly convert from type ApplicationUser to Customers model.
Note ApplicationUser is using Microsoft ASPNET identity. I basically want to add new users who register to my Customers collection, which distinguishes them from my Clients collection. At the moment new users registered to not belong to either class.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        Customer customer = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await mUserManager.CreateAsync(customer, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {

            await mSignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);                    
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

    }


    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears your `ApplicationUser` does not derrive from `Customer` so this line is invalid:

```
Customer customer = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.. Ok, but I want to add the newly created user to my customer class. `Customer` is derived from `ApplicationUser` :
`public class Customer
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }    }`

Comment: +1. I've **resolved** the issue by changing `ApplicationUser` to `Customer` in below:
`{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        protected UserManager<Customer> mUserManager;
        protected SignInManager<Customer> mSignInManager;
        protected ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext;

        public AccountController(ApplicationDbContext context,
                                UserManager<Customer> userManager, 
                                SignInManager<Customer> signInManager)`
I guess I'd need to add same for `Client` too.